# Ubuntu 16.04 Server MySql open_file_limit won't go higher than 65536

Tags: mysql, ulimit, max-file-descriptors, file-descriptors

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 Server on XenServer and I'm running into an issue with MySql's open file limit.

Here's what I've done so far:

**sudo nano /etc/security/limits.conf [(reference)](http://duntuk.com/how-raise-ulimit-open-files-and-mysql-openfileslimit)**

```
* soft nofile 1024000
* hard nofile 1024000
* soft nproc 102400
* hard nproc 102400
mysql soft nofile 1024000
mysql hard nofile 1024000
```

**sudo nano /etc/init/mysql.conf [(reference)](https://serverfault.com/questions/440878/changing-open-files-limit-in-mysql-5-5)**

```
limit nofile 1024000 1024000
limit nproc 102400 102400
```

**sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf [(reference)](http://duntuk.com/how-raise-ulimit-open-files-and-mysql-openfileslimit)**

```
[mysqld_safe]
open_files_limit = 1024000


[mysqld]
open_files_limit = 1024000
```

When the above didn't work, I went on to the the following:

**sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf**

```
fs.file-max = 1024000
```

**sudo nano /etc/pam.d/common-session**

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

**sudo nano /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive**

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

**sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service**

```
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
```

When I log into my user account everything seems fine:

```
ulimit -Hn
1024000
ulimit -Sn
1024000
```

If I login as mysql it looks good too:

```
mysql@server:~$ ulimit -Hn
1024000
mysql@server:~$ ulimit -Sn
1024000
```

However, when I look at the proc:

```
ps -ef | grep mysql
cat /proc/1023/limits | grep open
Max open files  65536 65536 files
```

Or when I look at it in MySql:

```
mysql> show global variables like 'open%';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| open_files_limit | 65536 |
+------------------+-------+
```

**From the logs (/var/log/mysql/error.log ):**

2016-07-25T05:44:35.453668Z 0 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 65536 (request: 1024000)

I'm completely out of ideas here. In the beginning I did start with open_files_limit at 1024, and one of the above must have changed it, but I need it to go higher. I'm hitting this limit already as I have a lot of databases and tables that sometimes have a lot of partitions.

I've even tried numbers less aggressive than 1024000, with no luck.

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 28):

This worked for me on Ubuntu Xenial 16.04:

Create the dir `/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d`

Put in `/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/override.conf`:

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=1024000
```

Now execute

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart mysql.service
```

Yes indeed, `LimitNOFILE=infinity` actually seems to set it to 65536.

You can validate the above after starting MySQL by doing:

```
cat /proc/$(pgrep mysql)/limits | grep files
```

Comment: Since I came here first but felt a bit unhappy with adjusting some system file I found another thread explaining how to fix w/o risking service file overwritten on next upgrade: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849331/how-to-set-nginx-max-open-files/36423859#36423859

Comment: Thanks @cepharum. I updated the answer. Indeed we already experienced problems on our servers because we updated the repo file `/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service`. So we already moved to the method you refered to. I did forget to update my answer here. Thanks again for the reminder.

Comment: This command does not work: cat /proc/$(pgrep mysql)/limits | grep files

Comment: @BasilA This command only works once MySQL is running. Just tested it on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Can you help me. I tried make over 102400 , Like 10 mln it not possible. I need somethink do in kernel? i have pagination over  99.biliosn records