# Ubuntu 16.10 Server MariaDB (MySql) open_file_limit won't go higher than 16364

Tags: mysql, ulimit, max-file-descriptors, file-descriptors

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.10 (yakkety yak) with MariaDB 10.x and experience the very same issue as [Ubuntu 16.04 Server MySql open_file_limit won't go higher than 65536](https://serverfault.com/questions/791729/ubuntu-16-04-server-mysql-open-file-limit-wont-go-higher-than-65536) with one exception, my open file limits is 16364

```
cat /proc/$(pgrep mysql)/limits | grep files
Max open files            16364                16364                files
```

I've searched a lot, and followed this guide, but nothing is changing the "Max Open Files" limit at all :(

Is there somebody who know the answer, or might be able to help?

Answer (score 4):

16K is the limit for LimitNOFILE for MariaDB, so you might want to increase that in the systemd service definition. For more details check this page: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/systemd/

Comment: Hi, that did it :) open_file_limit changed rigt away to given value

Comment: You can mark this as an answer then :)

Comment: jerichorivera I did :)